# Deny other users to edit data

Tags: php

I'm using an "edit" button that redirects the user to the update page, where he can edit his business datas. His business id appears on the google search bar. That was the only way I could solve to redirect him to his own business. The problem is, if he just rewrites the id on the search bar, he can modify anyone's datas.
Here's the button:

```
<a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $record['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-succes" role="button">Edit</a>
```

Comment: What you should actually edit is **update.php** file and add check whether the data belongs to logged in user.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: That depends on what is in update.php. What libraries you are using what framework etc.

Comment: Here's my full update.php code: https://pastebin.com/w3ZU9XtD

Comment: Which session id did you use in your login page?

Comment: I'm using userid as a foreign key to the user table 'id'

Comment: The session to compare to  in your update.php is the one you had set in your login page i.e. not `if( $_SESSION['id'] != $userid){  header("Location: index.php"); }`

Comment: Yes, I've tried it but it always redirects me to index.php and don't understand why.

Comment: Than check what values you have in $_SESSION['id'] and as $userid. 
var_dump(), print_r(), die();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
if($_SESSION['id'] != $id){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

In given code you are assigning 
on line 30.

```php
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
```

So on line 32. you are checking if $_SESSION['id'] != $_SESSION['id']
Also make sure you got correct value in your $_SESSION['id']

Comment: It also redirects me to the index page. Where I show the user's businesses, I'm using this: https://pastebin.com/ghjx6qCf and it's working there.

Comment: I pasted var_dump($_SESSION); and it says ["userid"]=> NULL but how can it be NULL? What should I change?

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: How can we know it? We don't have your login form we don't know where you are setting that value.